# Is there inherent selfishness within altruism?

Tags: logic, death

Recently I have been noticing a theme on my social media. There is a post of someone passing away. Within that post the comment section is filled with comments such as:

**"I lost my mother 4 years ago. I am sorry for your loss."**

**"I just saw him 3 days ago and he seemed totally fine. I am sorry for your loss."**

**Etc. . .**

To me, these types of comments are borderline selfish and inconsiderate towards the grieving person who posted that their loved one had passed. I struggle with this for 2 reasons.

1) I find myself being judgmental towards the person in the comment section. After all, they most likely have Noble intentions.

2) I struggle when trying to console someone who is grieving because I am hypersensitive on not coming off as selfish. Which in turn sometimes makes conversations short and seemingly inconsiderate in and of themselves.

I would truly appreciate any insight or work from notable philosophers that could shed some light on this subject.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: While the intention can be very different, the end result of saying something out of empathy or out of self-interest can be very similar.

Comment: It is not selfishness, it is empathy. By recalling their own losses people try to demonstrate that they are not making a mere verbal gesture, but share the emotions as well. Your concern over selfishness is oversized. Mackie in Ethics argues that human altruism is necessarily self-referential:"*The happiness with which I, inevitably, most concerned is my own, and next that of those who are in some way closely related to me... There is nothing wrong with self-love and confined generosity in themselves.*" Empathy is a way to extend this confined generosity to strangers.

Comment: Some people are just so self-absorbed that's what they do. Forgive them, they're doing their best. I disagree with @Conifold that it's empathy. Unless in some particular case it is. But mostly it's because your loss triggered their feelings about their own loss. So they use you to wallow in their own misery for a while. Human nature. This Mackie fellow, he's a glass half full guy I bet. Looking on the bright side.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I think what I have a problem with may lie more in the fact that these quick "sorry for your loss, here's something about myself" comments are happening on a Facebook wall. If I was mourning a loss and someone came to me in person and said "I am sorry for your loss. I lost my mother 4 years ago" that might spark a conversation and we may be able to console each other. On a Facebook post these comments come across as borderline inconsiderate although the intensions may not be so.

Comment: @user4894 That's nonsense.  Both of these could be innocent; the former a form of relating (as opposed to "exploitative massochism"), the latter could merely be an expression of shock followed by sorrow.  I'm not claiming they always *are* innocent, but since they *could* be, and since this is the only information you have, it's a bit paranoid to just pass judgment like that.  FYI, Desmond, I agree they both can sound insensitive, and laud you for your caution, but still offer that one should tend towards being charitable and reserving judgment *unless* you have good reason not to be.

Comment: @HWalters Describing my observations and ascribing them to simple human nature, is what I did. You call it nonsense and paranoid? Ok. If that's how you see it. You said nothing to make me alter my view. You simply informed me that the mere fact that I hold my views, triggers you to insult. If you're an introspective person you'll reflect on that.

Comment: @HWalters thank you! I understand I should be reserving judgment. It's sometimes easier said than done! Which is one reason I struggle with this concept.

Comment: Is it even logical to have this discussion if the writer of such consolation messages did not *mean* the things which are being debated/discussed here? Such detailed analysis of 'language game', in my opinion, will not prove helpful; and will give insights which are highly formal, and were in no way *meant* by the speaker. Since death is inevitable, sharing personal experiences is one way to help the sufferer come to terms with *this* fact, and help him see the world in a way which might help him to recover emotionally.

Comment: How things come off is very sensitive to whom they come off to, especially sight unseen. What exactly could be expected from online comments instead? What would be considerate? Perhaps the person posting on Facebook wanted just this sort of consolation: you are not alone, it happened to others too, we feel for you, it does get better. Yes, it lacks the nuance of face to face, Facebook can only simulate human contact so far. But as they say, it is the thought that counts. And if not, why post on Facebook in the first place?

Comment: Buddhist Parable of the Mustard Seed: As the day became evening and then night, she was still without any of the mustard seeds that she had been instructed to collect. She realized then the universality of death. According to the Buddhist verse her story comes from, she said:
“It’s not just a truth for one village or town, Nor is it a truth for a single family. But for every world settled by gods [and men] This indeed is what is true-- impermanence."  http://christicenter.org/2012/11/buddhism-parable-mustard-seed/

Comment: It is just such a shock for us humans to switch from our day to day living and our mundane affairs upon hearing of a death, that we seek to share our experience with this "sudden" realization of impermanence. That impermanence is the true state of affairs.